# Job executed with no data in Spark Streaming

Tags: streaming, apache-spark

My code:

```
// messages is JavaPairDStream<K, V> 
Fun01(messages)
Fun02(messages)
Fun03(messages)
```

Fun01, Fun02, Fun03 all have transformations, output operations (foreachRDD) .

1. Fun01, Fun03 both executed as expected, which prove "messages" is not null or empty.
2. On Spark application UI, I found Fun02's output stage in "Spark stages", which prove "executed".
3. The first line of Fun02 is a map function, I add log in it. I also add log for every step in Fun02, they all prove "with no data".

Does somebody know possible reasons? Thanks very much.

---

@maasg  Fun02's logic is:

```
msg_02 = messages.mapToPair(...)
msg_03 = msg_02.reduceByKeyAndWindow(...)
msg_04 = msg_03.mapValues(...)
msg_05 = msg_04.reduceByKeyAndWindow(...)
msg_06 = msg_05.filter(...)

msg_07 = msg_06.filter(...)
msg_07.cache()
msg_07.foreachRDD(...)
```

I have done test on Spark-1.1 and Spark-1.2, which is supported by my company's Spark cluster.

Comment: Could you add the missing code? It's not clear what the problem or potential cause is with the limited  context provided.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it. It is more helpful for other people and for those looking to help...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug in Spark-1.1 and Spark-1.2, fixed in Spark-1.3 .

I post my test result here: http://secfree.github.io/blog/2015/05/08/spark-streaming-reducebykeyandwindow-data-lost.html .

When continuously use two reduceByKeyAndWindow, depending of the window, slide value, "data lost" may appear.

I can not find the bug in Spark's issue list, so I can not get the patch.